# Command for specific search in a file and dump into other file

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am asking for some help from someone who is familiar with **grep** or **awk** best uses so i can reach my objectives.

We have a interface contract with an application that sends to our server ( Redhat ) a csv file with information about the presence of the staff of our team.
The file is made like this :

```
staff_id1|PPAAPPPAAAPPPAAPAPAPPPAAA...
staff_id2|PPPPPPPPPAPAPAPAAAPPAPAPP...
.........|....
```

- ***P : Present & A : Absent***
- ***Each P and A represents half a day.***
- ***So 2 of them is a day***
- ***Number of A&P's is : 800 before today and 800 after today***
- ***With a total of 1602 A&P's***
- ***800 for 400 days befor today, 2 for today, 800 for 400 days after
  today***

My objective in first place is to get only P&A's from today + after, so i need to collect from number 801 to 1602. After collecting for each staff member id the wanted characters, i want to regroup them into days like this :

```
AA To 0 => full day absent
AP To 1 => pm present
PA To 2 => am present
PP To 3 => full day present
```

separated with comas or ";" ideally so i can load the new file into the database.

```
staff_id1;0;1;1;1;0;2;0;0;3;3;2;0;0;1;2;2;0;3;0
staff_id2;0;1;1;1;0;2;0;0;3;3;2;0;0;1;2;2;0;3;0
...;...;...
```

I know that it's a really specific question but i need at least a first help so i can start.

Any comment observation or help would be great.

TY !

Comment: Please always try to add your efforts in your posts as we all are here to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$ cat file
staff_id1|PPAAPPPAAAPPPAAPAPAPPPAA
staff_id2|PPPPPPPPPAPAPAPAAAPPAPAP

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS  = "[|]"
    OFS = ";"
    map["AA"] = 0
    map["AP"] = 1
    map["PA"] = 2
    map["PP"] = 3
}
{
    n = length($2) - 1
    printf "%s", $1
    for (i=1; i<=n; i+=2) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, map[substr($2,i,2)]
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
staff_id1;3;0;3;2;0;3;2;1;1;1;3;0
staff_id2;3;3;3;3;2;2;2;2;0;3;1;1
```

wrt your comment below, MAYBE this is what you're asking to do in a shell script:

```
file='file.csv'  # or file="$1" if you're passing a parameter to a shell script.

awk '
    BEGIN {
    ...
    }
' "$file"
```

Comment: If i need to automise this operation, how can i add the awk -f in the file ? 
I've tried by adding the awk - f befor BEGIN and adding simple variable $file ="file.csv" and replace the $2 with it. But since i don't quite understand why you print the $1 which is the awk file itself i could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question but it sounds like you might be confusing awk and shell syntax. $1 in awk is the first field on the current input line, whereas $1 in shell is the first positional parameter passed to the script. I added something at the bottom of my answer that might help but if not then post a new question about whatever the issue is and I'm sure someone can help you.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.
But yes my objective is to have a script shell so i can schedule it as a job.

Comment: Your English was fine, no problem at all with that. Sounds like what I added to my answer is what you were asking about then, right?

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution by tweaking my previous solution itself along with delimiter now.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="|"
  OFS=";"
}
{
  num=split($2,array,"");
  for(i=1;i<=num;i+=2){
  val1=(val1?val1 OFS:"")\
       (array[i]=="A" && array[i+1]=="A"?0:\
       (array[i]=="A" && array[i+1]=="P"?1:\
       (array[i]=="P" && array[i+1]=="A"?2:\
       (array[i]=="P" && array[i+1]=="P"?3:"")\
)))}
  print $1 FS val1;
  val1=""
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you(tested with GNU `awk`).

```
awk -F"|" '
{
  num=split($2,array,"");
  for(i=1;i<=num;i+=2){
  val1=val1 (array[i]=="A" && array[i+1]=="A"?0:\
            (array[i]=="A" && array[i+1]=="P"?1:\
            (array[i]=="P" && array[i+1]=="A"?2:\
            (array[i]=="P" && array[i+1]=="P"?3:"")\
)))}
  print $1 FS val1;
  val1=""
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Splitting on null strings (e.g. `split($2,array,"")`) is undefined behavior per POSIX so your code will behave differently in different awks. It'll do what you want in GNU awk but not in some others. I'm also not 100% convinced that using `|` as the FS will behave as you want in all awks since you want it treated as a literal character but it's actually a regexp metacharacter. That's why I used `"[|]"` in mine, to make **sure** it behaves as I want (and it helps readability for anyone wondering what the intent is).

Comment: @EdMorton, yeah since I have only GNU `awk` so I have added note in solution that I have tested it in the same, will try to make a generic solution too and post it here if I would do so, cheers.

Comment: It'd be good to always run your code with `--posix` and `--lint` one time to see if behaves as expected and without warnings so you know if each of your scripts is portable or not. For example, try running the command `awk 'BEGIN{split("abc",t,""); print gensub(/./,"X",1,t[1])}'` vs adding those 2 flags to get `awk --lint --posix 'BEGIN{split("abc",t,""); print gensub(/./,"X",1,t[1])}'` and notice all the error and warning messages from the 2nd one.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure, yeah I saw errors are coming, you are AWESOME sir, will try to make a genuine solution.

Comment: Your ternary expression could be more concise, btw: `( array[i]=="A" ? (array[i+1]=="A"?0:1) :  (array[i+1]=="A"?2:3) )`

Comment: EDIT : Hi @RavinderSingh13, thanks for the help, 
The two commands runs perfectly, I'd prefer the first one since each digit is seperated with a ';'.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Could you please send me to a basic how to of awk so i can modify your work as some carachters may be added ? 
Thank you !

Comment: @Brad, to be honest, I have learnt `awk` by practicing in SO only, you could go through O Reilly book it is good to start with and then go to all posts in here you will learn a TONS of things over here, cheers.